# Populating one List using another c#

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I have a `List<Song>`, where song class has `string Title`, `string Artist` and `string Image`. Although I have 3 `Lists<string>` : `Titles`, `Artists` and `Images`. How can populate a List using these 3 lists without loop?

I don't need loop because lists are too long and it takes 10 seconds to complete. Asynchronous operation isn't suitable in this case.

### **EDIT**

```
    private Task GetPopularSongsAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var html = WebManager.GetPageAsync("http://myzuka.me/");
            html.Wait();

            var document = new HtmlParser().Parse(html.Result);

            var titles = document.DocumentElement.QuerySelectorAll(".player-inline p a");
            var artists = document.DocumentElement.QuerySelectorAll(".player-inline .details");
            var ids = document.DocumentElement.QuerySelectorAll(".player-inline").Select(m => m.GetAttribute("id")).ToList();


            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) // 20 is a random number for testing. It's usualy near 300-500
            {
                var newSong = new Song()
                {
                    Title = titles[i].InnerHtml,
                    Artist = GetArtistsFromInstance(artists[i].QuerySelectorAll("a.strong")),
                    Size = "12.3",
                    Bitrate = 320,
                    Length = 12.3,
                    Id = Regex.Replace(ids[i], @"[^\d]", "").Trim()
                };

                Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    NewSongs.Add(newSong);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking.  Are the lists of different types?

Comment: I understand that you have three list of strings for Titles, Artists, Images and you want to create a list of Song with data taken from these string lists. Is this right?

Comment: I'm sorry, stackoverflow editor deleted brackets. The target list is of type Song, and the others use string type

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Show us the code you wrote that is taking too long and maybe we can tell you how to improve it.

Comment: As far as I know you will need a loop somewhere.

Comment: I think you may have some misunderstandings on the async/await pattern...

Comment: You're right, I started to learn it yesterday and understood only a few words, but as for me the best way to learn something new is practice. As I understood, to run some code asynchronously I need to put it into lambda and return it from a task

Comment: Thats not quite right.  You will likely benefit from some more documentation reading or more tutorials.  It takes a while to click so don't be discouraged

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot wrong with your code.  First off **you are using async/await wrong**.

With async/await 99% of the time you want to have `async` all the way down your call stack.  Take a look at the code below:

```
//Marked the method as async
private async Task GetPopularSongsAsync()
{
    //Now we can await the async method
    var html = await WebManager.GetPageAsync("http://myzuka.me/");

    var document = new HtmlParser().Parse(html.Result);

    var titles = document.DocumentElement.QuerySelectorAll(".player-inline p a");
    var artists = document.DocumentElement.QuerySelectorAll(".player-inline .details");
    var ids = document.DocumentElement.QuerySelectorAll(".player-inline").Select(m => m.GetAttribute("id")).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i <= ids.Length; i++)
    {
        var newSong = new Song()
        {
            Title = titles[i].InnerHtml,
            Artist = GetArtistsFromInstance(artists[i].QuerySelectorAll("a.strong")),
            Size = "12.3",
            Bitrate = 320,
            Length = 12.3,
            Id = Regex.Replace(ids[i], @"[^\d]", "").Trim()
        };
        //No need to run a task to add to the list, just add it
        NewSongs.Add(newSong);
    }
}
```

Now you shouldn't be deadlocking your code.  From there you can

You should really look at the [best practices for async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot of detail here. I'm going to assume Titles, Artists, and Images are all the same length with Song components at identical indexes in their respective lists, and offer the following solution for you to consider:

```
Song[] songs = new Song[Titles.Length];
Parallel.For(0, Titles.Length,
               index => 
                {
                    songs[index] = new Song
                    {
                        Title = Titles.ElementAt(index),
                        Artist = Artists.ElementAt(index),
                        Image = Images.ElementAt(index)
                    }
                });
return songs.ToList();
```

Comment: While this technically works, this does not address the "speed" problem OP is having (due to the deadlocking).

Comment: If you need an async method, make sure you look at maccettura's answer first and do the async/await pattern correctly. If you want to attempt to construct the list of Songs faster afterwards, take a look at this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work, but I must be missing a key requirement; that is, how are the title, artist, and image related?  Otherwise, it's just a massive Cartesian join.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lists
{
    public class Song
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Artist;
        public string Image;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format( "Title = {0}, Artist = {1}, Image = {2}", Title, Artist, Image.Replace("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:", string.Empty) );
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main( string [] args )
        {
            List< string > titles = new List< string > { "Dazed And Confused", "Iron Man", "Young Lust" };
            List< string > artists = new List< string > { "Led Zeppelin", "Black Sabbath", "Pink Floyd" };
            List< string > images = new List< string > { 
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Led_Zeppelin_-_Led_Zeppelin_(1969)_front_cover.png", 
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black_Sabbath_-_Paranoid.jpg", 
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PinkFloydWallCoverOriginalNoText.jpg"
            };

            var songs = titles.SelectMany(
                t => artists.SelectMany(
                    a => images,
                    ( a, i ) => new Song { Title = t, Artist = a, Image = i } ) );

            foreach ( var song in songs )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( song );
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, it's right. Thanks. P.S.: You have chosen the coolest songs in the world)